# CentOS: what impact does a kernel update have?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

When running this on CentOS 6:

```
yum update
```

I get this:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 2:irqbalance-1.0.4-6.el6.x86_64 (base)
    Requires: kernel >= 2.6.32-279
    Installed: kernel-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201107091641.x86_64/6.0)
       kernel = 2.6.32-71.el6
       kernel = 2.6.32-71.el6
    Installed: kernel-2.6.32-220.4.2.el6.x86_64 (@updates)
       kernel = 2.6.32-220.4.2.el6
       kernel = 2.6.32-220.4.2.el6
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What exactly does a kernel update do and is this just a routine update or something that should be treated as a major change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel is the lowest component of your operating system, so it affects basically everything on your system. However, in CentOS (and in RHEL), kernel upgrades are usually just only minor bug fixes and security updates (except between dot-versions, ie. 6.4 -> 6.5) so they are fairly routine.

However, the kernel update is not as routine upgrade as an ordinary package upgrade, because it requires rebooting system afterwards for the update to take effect. In addition updating kernel contain other tasks (that are mostly automatically done), for instance, generating new initrd (used in booting) or perhaps reconfiguring vmware-tools, if you are running under VMware. In any case, kernel updates are fairly frequent, and fairly routine affair, even if bit more complex than regular updates.